# Neo4j - Cypher: mutual object with traversing relationships

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a small Graph:

```
CREATE 
(Dic1:Dictioniary { name:'Dic1' }),
(Dic2:Dictioniary { name: 'Dic2' }),
(Dic3:Dictioniary { name: 'Dic3' }),
(File1:File { name: 'File1' }),
(File2:File { name: 'File2' }),
(File3:File { name: 'File3' }),
(Dic2)-[:contains]->(Dic1),
(Dic1)-[:contains]->(File1),
(Dic3)-[:contains]->(File2),
(File1)-[:references]->(File3),
(File2)-[:references]->(File3)
```

I need a cypher query to find out, if for example Dic2 and Dic3 have paths/relations, where they reference the same File.
In this case it would be true; the mutual File is File3.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are looking for just two dictionaries you can achieve this in a single statement:

```
MATCH (d2:Dictioniary { name:'Dic2' }),(d3:Dictioniary { name:'Dic3' })
MATCH (d2)-[:contains|references*]->(f:File)<-[:contains|references*]-(d3)
RETURN f
```

It is quite expensive due to the two unbounded path matches, but it is quite cheap as it is bound from  the outset by the two dictionary matches.

If you had an arbitrary number of Dictionaries to test you could do something like:

```
MATCH (d1:Dictioniary { name:'Dic1' }),(d2:Dictioniary { name:'Dic2' }),(d3:Dictioniary { name:'Dic3' })
WITH [d1,d2,d3] AS ds
MATCH (d)-[:contains|references*]->(f:File)
WHERE d IN ds
WITH f, ds, COLLECT(d) AS fds
WHERE length(ds)= length(fds)
RETURN f
```

This matches the dictionaries that you are interested in first and for each of them in turn it finds the files that they reference. Importantly the File object is preserved and the Dictionary that referenced it is collected into an array (`fds`). If we know that we had 3 dictionaries to begin with (`length(ds)`) and that a given file has the same number of related dictionaries (`length(fds)`) then all dictionaries must reference it.

Assuming that there may multiple paths to a given File from a given Dictionary then you can insert the `DISTINCT`modifier into the second `WITH` statement:

```
WITH f, ds, COLLECT(DISTINCT(d)) AS fds
```